# How to receive the socket.io client side event in node.js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, socket.io

In my application im using socket.io with node.js.Receiving client side event in main app file is working fine.But receiving event in other node.js modules not working for me.Can anyone help me on this.

Client side js file

```
  var fullName=$("#fullName").val();
  var emailId=$("#emailId").val(); 
  var contactNo=$("#ContactNo").val();
  var msg=$("#message").val();
  var userInfo={fName:fullName,email:emailId,contactNumber:contactNo,message:msg};
  var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8000');
  socket.emit('uploadResume',userInfo);
```

app.js - Server side main file

```
  var express = require('express')
               , http = require('http');

  var app = express();
  app.configure(function(){
     app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
  });
 var server = http.createServer(app);
 var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
 server.listen(8000);

 exports.io=io;
 console.log('io object is set.');
 var mongodb = require('mongodb');
 var server = new mongodb.Server("localhost", 27017, {});

 new mongodb.Db('test', server, {w: 1}).open(function (error, client) {


    exports.client = client;
    console.log('client object is set.');

 });
```

Notification.js

```
 console.log('Notification module is called');

var app=require('../server');
console.log('app module is ready to use.');
var ioObj=app.io;
var clientObj=app.client;

ioObj.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
socket.on('uploadResume', function (userInfo) {
 console.log('data is '+userInfo); 
 var collection = new mongodb.Collection(clientObj, 'test_collection');
  collection.insert(userInfo,{safe:true},function(err, objects) {
    if(!err){

     console.log('Data inserted successfully.');
    }
    if (err && err.message.indexOf('E11000 ') !== -1) {
      // this _id was already inserted in the database
    }
  });




   });
 });
```

Console msg

```
   info  - socket.io started
   io object is set.
   client object is set.
   debug - served static content /socket.io.js
   debug - client authorized
   info  - handshake authorized g2Sx9h5FL9Gxzs3KiAcj
   debug - setting request GET /socket.io/1/websocket/g2Sx9h5FL9Gxzs3KiAcj
   debug - set heartbeat interval for client g2Sx9h5FL9Gxzs3KiAcj
   debug - client authorized for 
   debug - websocket writing 1::
   debug - emitting heartbeat for client g2Sx9h5FL9Gxzs3KiAcj
   debug - websocket writing 2::
   debug - set heartbeat timeout for client g2Sx9h5FL9Gxzs3KiAcj
   debug - got heartbeat packet
   debug - cleared heartbeat timeout for client g2Sx9h5FL9Gxzs3KiAcj
   debug - set heartbeat interval for client g2Sx9h5FL9Gxzs3KiAcj
   debug - emitting heartbeat for client g2Sx9h5FL9Gxzs3KiAcj
   debug - websocket writing 2::
   debug - set heartbeat timeout for client g2Sx9h5FL9Gxzs3KiAcj
   debug - got heartbeat packet
   debug - cleared heartbeat timeout for client g2Sx9h5FL9Gxzs3KiAcj
   debug - set heartbeat interval for client g2Sx9h5FL9Gxzs3KiAcj
   debug - emitting heartbeat for client g2Sx9h5FL9Gxzs3KiAcj
   debug - websocket writing 2::
   debug - set heartbeat timeout for client g2Sx9h5FL9Gxzs3KiAcj
   debug - got heartbeat packet
   debug - cleared heartbeat timeout for client g2Sx9h5FL9Gxzs3KiAcj
   debug - set heartbeat interval for client g2Sx9h5FL9Gxzs3KiAcj
   debug - emitting heartbeat for client g2Sx9h5FL9Gxzs3KiAcj
   debug - websocket writing 2::
   debug - set heartbeat timeout for client g2Sx9h5FL9Gxzs3KiAcj
   debug - got heartbeat packet
   debug - cleared heartbeat timeout for client g2Sx9h5FL9Gxzs3KiAcj
   debug - set heartbeat interval for client g2Sx9h5FL9Gxzs3KiAcj
   debug - emitting heartbeat for client g2Sx9h5FL9Gxzs3KiAcj
   debug - websocket writing 2::
   debug - set heartbeat timeout for client g2Sx9h5FL9Gxzs3KiAcj
   debug - got heartbeat packet
   debug - cleared heartbeat timeout for client g2Sx9h5FL9Gxzs3KiAcj
   debug - set heartbeat interval for client g2Sx9h5FL9Gxzs3KiAcj
   debug - emitting heartbeat for client g2Sx9h5FL9Gxzs3KiAcj
   debug - websocket writing 2::
   debug - set heartbeat timeout for client g2Sx9h5FL9Gxzs3KiAcj
   debug - got heartbeat packet
   debug - cleared heartbeat timeout for client g2Sx9h5FL9Gxzs3KiAcj
   debug - set heartbeat interval for client g2Sx9h5FL9Gxzs3KiAcj
   debug - emitting heartbeat for client g2Sx9h5FL9Gxzs3KiAcj
   debug - websocket writing 2::
   debug - set heartbeat timeout for client g2Sx9h5FL9Gxzs3KiAcj
   debug - got heartbeat packet
   debug - cleared heartbeat timeout for client g2Sx9h5FL9Gxzs3KiAcj
   debug - set heartbeat interval for client g2Sx9h5FL9Gxzs3KiAcj
```

Comment: Could you specify what console messages are being printed when the server is run?

Comment: Code seems to be correct.. please give more details on what error or output you are getting....

Comment: @AmolMKulkarni  pls check i have updated console messages in my code

Comment: @shelman pls check i have updated console messages in my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on your main app file you have to include the module

app.js

```
  var notification=require('./Notifications.js');  // module included
  var express = require('express'),
  http = require('http');

  var app = express();
  app.configure(function(){
     app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
  });
 var server = http.createServer(app);
 var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
 server.listen(8000);

 exports.io=io;
 console.log('io object is set.');
 var mongodb = require('mongodb');
 var server = new mongodb.Server("localhost", 27017, {});

 new mongodb.Db('test', server, {w: 1}).open(function (error, client) {


    exports.client = client;
    console.log('client object is set.');

 });
```

So if you don't include the module file in to the main app.js file it wont work